# C#: Prevent certificate selection window in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, certificate, ssl-certificate, webbrowser-control

I have developed a Windows Form application that provide a WebBrowser control. The Homepage is a https site that require a specific certificate. I would like to automatically load the certificate from a predefined path and disable the popup of certificate selection.

Is it possible in C#?